# How can I define a datatype with 1 bit size in C?

Tags: c, boolean, bit, declare

I want to define a datatype for boolean true/false value in C. Is there any way to define a datatype with 1 bit size to declare for boolean?

Comment: You know that you cant address less than a byte, so it will consume more memory than one bit no matter what you do (unless you pair it up with 7 others bits yourself).

Comment: If I want to define a datatype with 1 byte then what's the procedure?I dont want to use int for boolean.

Comment: Have you seen the boolean type defined in others' code? Is there something wrong with existing solutions?

Comment: in the existing solution the boolean type is defined as unsigned char.so when I put this value in conditional operator(if/else) it's not working.

Comment: It is not possible to allocate less than 1 byte.

Comment: Which version of which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a bit-field:

```
struct bitfield
{
     unsigned b0:1;
     unsigned b1:1;
     unsigned b2:1;
     unsigned b3:1;
     unsigned b4:1;
     unsigned b5:1;
     unsigned b6:1;
     unsigned b7:1;
};
```

There are so many implementation-defined features to bit-fields that it is almost unbelievable, but each of the elements of the `struct bitfield` occupies a single bit.  However, the size of the structure may be 4 bytes even though you only use 8 bits (1 byte) of it for the 8 bit-fields.

There is no other way to create a single bit of storage.  Otherwise, C provides bytes as the smallest addressable unit, and a byte must have at least 8 bits (historically, there were machines with 9-bit or 10-bit bytes, but most machines these days provide 8-bit bytes only — unless perhaps you're on a DSP where the smallest addressable unit may be a 16-bit quantity).

Comment: "Almost everything about [bit] fields is implementation-dependent." --K&R, Section 6.9 also refer http://blog.reverberate.org/2009/06/bit-fields-in-c99.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

In my opinion use a variable of type `int`. That is what we do in C. For example:

```
int flag=0;
if(flag)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can specify the size of the fields in a structure of bits fields in bits. However the compiler will round the type to at the minimum the nearest byte so you save nothing and the fields are not addressable and the order that bits in a bit field are stored is implementation defined. Eg:

```
struct A {
  int a : 1; // 1 bit wide
  int b : 1;
  int c : 2; // 2 bits
  int d : 4; // 4 bits
};
```

Bit-fields are only allowed inside structures. And other than bit-fields, no object is allowed to be smaller than sizeof(char).

Comment: In int it costs 4 byte. I want 1 bit declaration.is it possible?

Comment: @NutBoltu - We have moved on since the abacus!

Comment: @EdHeal: Thats ok! He is trying to learn. In fact, we all are :-)

Comment: Why not use `char` instead of `int`? It's one byte instead of 2 bytes or 4 bytes. Even `short` is larger than `char` (since we're not doing Java)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is _Bool or bool.

C99 and later have a built-in type _Bool which is guaranteed to be large enough to store the values 0 and 1. It may be 1 bit or larger, and it is an integer.

They also have a library include  which provides a macro bool which expands to _Bool, and macros true and false that expand to 1 and 0 respectively.

If you are using an older compiler, you will have to fake it.

[edit: thanks Jonathan]

Comment: Technically, C99 and C11 have a built-in type `_Bool` which is always available; `<stdbool.h>` provides a macro `bool` which expands to `_Bool`, and macros `true` and `false` that expand to 1 and 0 respectively, and a macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` to let you know that `<stdbool.h>` has been included.  As a special privilege, to be revoked in the (dim distant) future, you are allowed to undefine and redefine the `bool`, `true` and `false` macros.